# Why does the AT-AT Driver spell out the word DECIMAL?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

As Imperial Walkers are closing in on the Rebel Base on Hoth in The Empire Strikes Back, General Veers asks how far they are from the **Power Generators**:

> VEERS: Distance to power generators?
>
> PILOT: One-seven, **decimal** two-eight.

Why would the Pilot say **DECIMAL** - not to mention saying **One-seven**? It would seem to be quicker and more understandable for anyone to use **Seventeen point twenty-eight** instead.

Did the original script say **Decimal** or was this improvisation on the part of the actor?

Please explain any reason (in-universe or out) to say each individual number or the word DECIMAL like this (maybe IRL pilots in bombers do this for accuracy).

Comment: Same reason naval aviators spell out everything now.

Comment: According to the [script on IMSDb](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Empire-Strikes-Back.html), this is indeed how it is written in the script, not something the actor made up. I don’t know military conventions for reading numbers well enough to comment on this particular style.

Comment: You certainly wouldn't want to say "Seventeen point twenty-eight"; too much risk of it being confused with "Seventy point twenty-eight" (among other possible confusions perhaps).

Comment: Who says seventeen point twenty eight anyway? Surely you mean Seventeen **point two eight**

Comment: voting to close

Comment: This question seems less about Star Wars and more about English language usage. On-topic for both, but arguably far more on-topic there than here.

Comment: The screenplay says "one-seven, decimal two-eight".

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic: it's asking about a production (script) issue of a work of science fiction. It's just not very well researched :\ The bigger question is, do the movies stick to this convention consistently?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield - I'm not gonna close it. By the same token, I wouldn't be broken-hearted if it got closed.

Comment: I asked why they use **DECIMAL** here because this is the only place in SW that it is ever used. 
"She'll make **point** five beyond the speed of light." 
"Rendezvous at mark six **point** one."

Comment: @HannoverFist:   So what?   People aren't allowed to use different words for the same thing in Galactic Basic?!  Especially weak considering one is a pseudo-military context and the other is a smuggler bragging.

Comment: Just spitballing here, but my pet theory has always been that this is to prevent confusion between different standards of notation. In the real world, some countries use "." and others use "," as decimal separator, so saying "decimal" would be clearer, especially during the OT when the stormtroopers were recruited from all over the galaxy and didn't necessarily share a standard dialect. The artificially uniform accent that they seem to adopt (despite most of them not being clones by then), the usage of "decimal", etc., is an attempt at standardization, to prevent confusion and disorder.

Answer (score 22):

Standard radio procedure and phonetics has a specific way that every letter and number is pronounced on the radio to avoid confusion by the receiver.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet shows the proper pronunciation for each number and letter used.

At the end of the number list, "decimal point" is shown as pronounced as "DAY-SEE-MAL" over comms. As well, until you get into hundred or thousand, the only numbers are 0-9, therefore double digit figures must be "spelled" out.

Comment: Seems like the better question is why did anyone ever say "point" in Star Wars.

Answer (score 15):

What you're referring to is called "[**Voice Procedure**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_procedure)" (or sometimes "Vocal Procedure"). It was formulated not long after the invention of the [telegraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_telegraph), and is a way of carefully enunciating specific letters/numbers in order to minimize confusion on the other end. With the advent of widespread [radio communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio) in the [First World War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_War_I), this standard was modified and adopted by the major militaries of the world.

As most sci-fi militaries take their cue from modern militaries, this form of spoken communication has been used for what we see on-screen as well. For instance, it can be seen in [Star Trek: The Next Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation) whenever coordinates are called out:

> **PICARD:** Mr. La Forge, take us out of orbit.
>
> **GEORDI:** Destination, sir?
>
> **PICARD:** I don't care. Let's just get some distance between us and this system.
>
> **GEORDI:** Aye, sir. Course ***9-7-0 Mark 3-1-8***, speed... warp 3.
>
> **RIKER:** Where will that take us, Mr. La Forge?
>
> **GEORDI:** The Opperline system.
>
> **RIKER:** An interesting choice. Why?
>
> **GEORDI:** Curiosity. We've never been there.
>
> **PICARD:** Engage.

Use of the term "decimal" is proper according to the standard, but the word "mark" is sometimes used to indicate a decimal or exact point in time, depending on the context of the message at the time. Using "decimal" instead may have been an attempt by Lucas to make the Empire seem more alien to a modern audience.

Comment: I don't think "mark" in ST was based on any real-world usage of mark (though US military does use "tack" instead of "dash"). "decimal" and "point" are both used for coordinates that are real numbers. Having said that, the fact that *any* radio-based military is going to have it's own voice procedure is right on point... (no pun intended)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield : the only one I'm sure about is Air Force - their pilots are trained to use "mark", or at least they were 20,30 years ago when I was growing up around the bases.

Comment: I thought the military usage of "mark" was used in terms of "marking" a target, not as a replacement for "point"? In ST, it's not use as a decimal, it's used to indicate the separation between two coordinates, like "970 mark 318" is basically "970 latitude, 318 longitude" (apparently, using some kind of wierd 1000 degree scale.)

Comment: @ Michael Edenfield
You are correct. It is NOT used to replace the decimal.

Comment: That same coordinate system in ST, when written, is written as 970.318

Comment: Maybe in Star Trek, but in Star WARS (which the original question is about) or real life, its not the case.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield:   Yes, it is explicitly explained in Datalore that "mark" separates yaw angle from pitch angle.

Comment: Memory Alpha has a description of how bearing are given including the use of "mark" in Star Trek: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Bearing The ultimate source appears to be *Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual*.

Comment: The two course points between the decimal were meant to describe 360 degrees in a circle, the first for the X axis, and the second for the Y axis, so 970 makes no sense.